# Lottie-player loading JSON object/string into src attribute doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, lottie

I am using lottie player integrated with lottie-interactivity on my Vue.js project. I've encountered an issue that I'm not able to solve. When I pass a link to a .json file to the lottie-player, the animation loads fine, while if I try passing the json string/object directly it doesn't seem to load. Any help with this would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
<template>
<lottie-player 
        :id='lottie.id'
        :class="lottie.class"
        :ref='lottie.id'
        :src='lottie.file'>
</lottie-player>
```

```
<script>
import "@lottiefiles/lottie-player"
import { create } from '@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity'

export default {
  name: 'LottieAnimation',
  props:{
    lottie: {
        type: Object
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.lottie.file)
    this.$refs[this.lottie.id].addEventListener('load', () => {
        create({
            mode: this.lottie.mode,
            player: '#' + this.lottie.id,
            container: this.lottie.container,
            actions: this.lottie.actions
        });
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear where you're passing "a link to a .json file" vs "passing the json string/object directly". Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: According to the documentation in the :src attribute i can either pass a link to a json file as such "https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_UJNc2t.json" or pass the string of that json directly. After further investigating i found out that when i pass a string to that attribute the "load" event doesn't get triggered and thus the lottie-interactivity object doesn't get created. I tried multiple workaround so far that didn't seem to work. I tried listening for the "ready" event which seems to get triggered but the object creation fails somehow without any errors.

Comment: I tried setting a timeout and creating the lottie-interactivity object after the render which also didn't seem to work. And I've tried loading the file through javascript which also didn't give any positive results. The error seems to lie with the initialization of the lottie-interactivity object. Without the initialization of that library i cannot link the lottie to a scroll behaviour

Comment: Small Update for anyone struggling with this, i found a workaround that seems to have finally worked, i added the following timeout to the mounted hook:       setTimeout(()=>{
          document.querySelector('lottie-player').load(this.lottie.file)
           if(!this.lottie.autoplay){
            create({
                mode: this.lottie.mode,
                player: '#' + this.lottie.id,
                container: this.lottie.container,
                actions: this.lottie.actions
            })}
      },10)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be that initial `src` is `null` and on the next render `src` is your json. `lottie-player` will not re-render if `src` gets changed - [Git issue](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player/issues/39).

JSON objects work as `src` attribute but you need to use `JSON.stringify(json)`.

You can listen for `src` change and load the player again, with new `src`. Here is the example in React but it causes blink effect, which is not really nice.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!prevSrc || prevSrc === src) {
      return;
    }

    const lottiePlayer = document.getElementById(`lottie-player-${src}`);

    if (lottiePlayer) {
      lottiePlayer.load(src);
    }
}, [src, prevSrc]);
```